# Is a Lipschitz bounded domain verifies (H)

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, functional-analysis, analysis, lipschitz-functions

In this [paper](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1685&context=math) They have defined the assumption (H) for an open $\Omega$ in $\mathbb R^d $ as:

> (H) $\Omega$ is a bounded, open, star-shaped domain  with respect to $x_0\in \operatorname{int}(\Omega)$, $B(x_0,\epsilon)\subset \Omega$, for some
>   $\epsilon>0$, there exists a finite partition of $\Omega$, $\Omega =\Omega_1\cup..\cup\Omega_p$, such that $\Omega_i$ is a cone with
>   vertex at $x_0$, $\partial \Omega\cap\partial\Omega_i\in\mathcal C^1$, $B(x_0, \epsilon)\cap \Omega_i$ is convex for all $i = 1, ..., p$. Further, we assume
>   that there exist $a > 0$ such that $v(x).x > a$ for all $x\in\partial\Omega$, where $v(x)$ denotes the outward unit
>   normal to $\partial\Omega$ at $x$.

My question is: if $U$ is a Lipschitz bounded, open, star-shaped domain, Is what $U$  satisfies (H).

Note that: We say that $\Omega$ is star-shaped with respect to an interior point $x_0\in \Omega$ , if any ray with origin at $x_0$ has a unique
common point with the boundary $\partial \Omega$.